# How to target HTML elements in .aspx file from the code behind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, datatable, datarow

I am using ASP.NET and C#:

I have data I wish to display in HTML elements on my webpage. At the moment I can display the data by creating a new div and paragraphs in the code behind but cannot target it to go into my existing HTML code . Below is where I created my div and paragraphs in my code behind

```
      //Populating a DataTable from database.
      DataTable dt = this.GetData();

      //Building an HTML string.
      StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

      //Div start.
      html.Append("<div>");                

      //Building the Data rows.
      foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                html.Append("<div>");
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {
                    html.Append("<p>");
                    html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                    html.Append("</p>");
                }
                html.Append("</div>");
            }

            //Div end.
            html.Append("</div>");
```

How can I target my existing HTML elements for my data to be displayed.

```
    <div class="deal-info">             
         <h3>Name</h3>
         <p>Description</p>
         <p>Location</p>
         <p>Price</p>
    </div>
```

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: You should not manually build up HTML with strings in your code behind. Instead, use a control that binds to your data source. A Repeater would be a good idea.

Comment: This looks very php-like, do not do this, use a repeater. Once you get the hang of it, your coding will become more efficient.

Comment: Hi thank you very much for the suggestions. I used a Repeater. I want each row from my database table to display in separate divs on my web page. At the moment it outputs all my rows of data in the div where I have placed my Repeater. Any suggestions to amend this?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can access every HTML object in your codebehind if you set it as runat server. Whether I would recommend it or not, here is how it works.

```
<div class="deal-info">             
     <h3>Name</h3>
     <p>Description</p>
     <p>Location</p>
     <p>Price</p>
</div>
<asp:PlaceHolder ID = 'yourplaceholder' runat = 'server' />

System.Text.StringBuilder html = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
//Any code...
//html.Append("..")
yourplaceholder.Controls.Add(new System.Web.UI.LiteralControl(html.ToString()));
```

or

```
<div class="deal-info" id = "yourplaceholder" runat = "server">             
     <h3>Name</h3>
     <p>Description</p>
     <p>Location</p>
     <p>Price</p>
</div>

System.Text.StringBuilder html = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
//Any code...
//html.Append("..")
```